# Why is PHP mail not sending to multiple recipients?

Tags: php, email

When using PHP's `mail()` function, I receive the email to both accounts when the "to" parameter is set to:

```
"test@example2.com,test@example1.com"
```

but when I swap them round:

```
"test@example1.com,test@example2.com"
```

the email is delivered to `test@example2.com` but not `test@example1.com`.  Nor does it receive the email if is specified as the CC or BCC header.

Can anybody suggest why this may be the case?  It was working fine up until a couple of weeks ago.  As far as I am aware nothing has changed on my server, though it's shared hosting so it's possible that it has.

Things to note: The `mail()` function always returns `true`, regardless of order. `example1.com` is also the sending server.

My code is as follows:

```
$from = 'sales@example1.com';

$headers = '';
$headers .= 'From: My Site <' . $from . ">\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["Email"] . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$body = 'Message goes here';

$to = 'test@example1.com,test@example2.com'; // will not send to test@example2.com, though will if the addresses are swapped

if ( mail( $to, 'Subject goes here', $body, $headers, '-f ' . $from ) ) {
    $url = "/contact/?message=sent";
} else {
    $url = "/contact/?message=failed";
}

header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: debugging mail delivery is like giving a cat a bath. but if if you have access to the server mail logs, that is where i would start.

Comment: are you sure the e-mails aren't being sent but instead they're caught by a spam filter?

Comment: Looking at the PHP Manual, I notice the example has a space after the comma..  `$to = 'test@example1.com, test@example2.com';`   
You could also use your headers section to add a CC

`$headers .= 'Cc: 2ndaddress@example.com' . "\r\n";`

Comment: I don't think it's spam related as I do receive the email if sent as the first address. The emails definitely don't arrive into my spam folders. Unfortunately I don't have access to the logs. It's worth noting too that it doesn't seem to matter what domain the second account belongs to, it always fails _unless_ the domain is also hosted on the same server as example1.com

Comment: `'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["Email"] . "\r\n" .`...whelp that's dangerous and 100% open to header injection. Have fun being blacklisted forever

Comment: You may want to talk to your host about that. If the second email will only deliver to server-hosted domains, they may have restrictions on the SMTP mailer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Fair point, though that _is_ a cut-down version of that section of code

Comment: I'll contact them @aynber - thanks

Comment: Could you show us the output of `echo ini_get('sendmail_path')`?

Comment: @EmilyShepherd /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Comment: Damn, unless the server is using some bizzare knock off of sendmail, that looks fine.

Comment: @EmilyShepherd you never know ;) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the PHP Manual, I notice the example has a space after the comma.. 
Try

```
$to = 'test@example1.com, test@example2.com';
```

You could also use your headers section to add a CC

```
$headers .= 'Cc: 2ndaddress@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: As noted in my question, the CC (not BCC) headers do not work either. I tried with a space after the comma but that didn't work either. Thanks though.